# How do I sort a nested sequence in clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming, nested-lists

I have a nested map in which the keys are numbers as follows:

```
{:18 [Lan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :33 [Man Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :3 [Tan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :6 [Jan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :5 [Han Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :7 [Fan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :1 [Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 345-7867], :9 [John Smith 123 Here Street 456-4567]}
```

which I want to sort on the basis of the first entry (i.e., keys) as follows:

```
{:1 [Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 345-7867], :3 [Tan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :5 [Han Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :6 [Jan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :7 [Fan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :9 [John Smith 123 Here Street 456-4567], :18 [Lan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533], :33 [Man Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533]}
```

However, the first entry in each list is treated as a string instead of an integer and the `sort/sort-by`
return a lexographically sorted list as follows. Please note that the mps is stored in the `new-map` variable in my program.

```
(do
    (into (sorted-map) new-map)
)
```

The output is:

```
([1 Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 345-7867] [18 Lan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533] [3 Tan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533] [33 Man Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533] [5 Han Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533] [6 Jan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533] [7 Fan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533] [9 John Smith 123 Here Street 456-4567])
```

How can I do this without using any loops? I am trying to avoid the use of loops here. However, a recursive function would be okay.

Comment: I've rolled back your latest edit. The content didn't match the title, the code examples clearly couldn't do what you say they did (you forgot to finish editing them), and it made the existing answer by Alan Thompson look a bit odd as it's answering a question you appeared not to have asked. Please keep question edits roughly in line with the original question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.  Just add:

```
(sort-by #(Integer/parseInt (first %)) new-list)
```

full code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [data [["18" "Lan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
              ["33" "Man Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
              ["3" "Tan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
              ["6" "Jan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
              ["5" "Han Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
              ["7" "Fan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
              ["1" "Sue Jones" "43" "Rose Court Street" "345-7867"]
              ["9" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"]]]
    (spyx-pretty (sort-by #(Integer/parseInt (first %)) data))))
```

with result

```
(["1" "Sue Jones" "43" "Rose Court Street" "345-7867"]
 ["3" "Tan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
 ["5" "Han Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
 ["6" "Jan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
 ["7" "Fan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
 ["9" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"]
 ["18" "Lan Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"]
 ["33" "Man Yuhong" "165" "Happy Lane" "345-4533"])
```

---

Update

For your modified question, [see the function](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) `group-by`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That was the kind of solution I was looking for and did exactly what I needed. I will look at the group-by function for the updated question or see if I can leverage the sorted list to create a sorted map.